# inherit template class using inner type as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Can I do something like this?

```
template<class T> struct A {

};

struct B : public A<B::X> {
    typedef string X;
};
```

In particular, I am trying to write an `Enumerator`, that is an iterator wrapper which also counts the number of iterations and dereferences to an object holding the iterator value and additionally providing access to the counter and few other functionality. Like this:

```
template<class Iterator>
struct Enumerator : public iterator<input_iterator_tag, Enumerator<Iterator>::value_type>
{
    typedef size_t counter_type;

    struct value_type
    {
        counter_type i;
        const typename Iterator::value_type& a;
        value_type(const counter_type& i, const typename Iterator::value_type& a) : i(i), a(a) {}
    };

    counter_type i;

    Iterator it;

    Enumerator() : i(0), it() {}
    Enumerator(const Iterator & it) : i(0), it(it) {}

    bool operator==(const Enumerator& a) const {return this->it==a.it;}
    bool operator!=(const Enumerator& a) const {return this->it!=a.it;}

    Enumerator& operator++() {++this->i; ++this->it; return *this;}
    Enumerator operator++(int) {Enumerator tmp(*this); this->operator++(); return tmp;}

    const value_type& operator*() const {return value_type(i,*this->it);}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `B` is an incomplete type at that point and incomplete types cannot be used in nested name specifiers.

You could move the definition of the struct to another class (`EnumeratorBase` below) and then do something like this:

```
template<class Iterator>
struct Enumerator
    : private EnumeratorBase<Iterator>
    , public iterator<input_iterator_tag, EnumeratorBase<Iterator>::value_type>

{
    using typename EnumeratorBase<Iterator>::value_type;    
};
```

Comment: The using keyword does not work for me in this case (`error: unknown type name 'value_type'`), but another typedef `typedef typename iterator<input_iterator_tag, typename EnumeratorBase<Iterator>::value_type>::value_type value_type;` in the derived class Enumerator does. Any idea why using is not useable here?

Comment: @user3503380 It's supposed to work even without it, g++ and clang accept it, so it may be a quirk with your compiler. It doesn't hurt to be there, though.

Comment: @user3503380 No wait, `typename` is required, of course. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do something like this?

No, you can't, because at the moment you use `B::X`, the type `B::X` (or the class `B` for that matter) is not completely declared.

An alternative would be to add a typedef in your `A` class:

```
template<class T> struct A {
    typedef T t_type;
};
```

and then `typedef` to it in your `B`:

```
struct B : public A<string> {
    typedef t_type X;
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75397ad7b12fc8ec)

Comment: As you see in the extended Iterator example I gave, I cannot really modify A. I guess @jrok's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, it's not possible. Because when you have the `struct B : public A<B::X>`, the type-alias `B::X` does not exist yet.

But if you know what type `X` will be, why not use that actual type instead? Like

```
struct B : public A<std::string>
{
    typedef std::string X;

    ...
};
```

Or make `B` a templated structure as well, with a default type for the template parameter:

```
template<typename T = std::string>
struct B : public A<T>
{
    typedef T X;

    ...
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know type `X`. Maybe I simplified the simplified example a bit too much. As you observe from the longer code snippet, the template parameter for the inherited class `iterator` depends on the template parameter `Iterator` of the inheriting class `Enumerator`.